# PHP Email form validating incorrectly

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, form-submit

I have a comment/questions form on my page. Before I implemented the 'submit' code, it would check for validation efforts. Now every time I click submit, it proceeds to my 'Message Sent' page, even when I know it won't page the validation.

I've checked some related answers, but couldn't get the answers to this one...

*Note: Removed some values to get to the main point

Main PHP:

```
<section style="-webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column;">

            <?php include '/home/ubuntu/workspace/commentform.php';?>

            <h2>Questions &amp; Concerns</h2><br>
            <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p><br>

            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="comment-handler.php">
                Full Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" style="width:22em">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br><br>
                Phone Number: (xxx) xxx-xxxx <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>" style="width:9.5em"><br><br>
                E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" style="width: 25em">
                <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>

                Comment:<br><sub>*500 Character Maximum.</sub>
                <textarea name="comment" size="500" maxlength="500" rows="10" column="50" style="width: 50em; height: 10em"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

        </section>
```

Error Handling Form

```
<?php
$nameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $invoiceErr = "";
$name  = $phone = $email = $invoice = $response = $comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $phone = "";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }
if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
        $comment = "";
    } else {
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment-Handler (submit-action) Form:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$callResponse = $_POST['callResponse'];
$textResponse = $_POST['textResponse'];
$emailResponse = $_POST['emailResponse'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$content = "Name: $name \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email \n\nInvoice #: $invoice \n\nContact Preference(s):\nCall: $callResponse   Text: $textResponse   Email: $emailResponse \n\n Question/Concern:\n\n $comment";



ini_set('display_errors',1);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = '7servicerepairs@gmail.com';
$subject = "New Question For Se7en Service!";
$txt = $content;
$headers = array("From: info@se7enservice.com", "Reply-To: $email");
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

    if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)) {
        include '/home/ubuntu/workspace/sentMessage.php';

    } else {
        echo '<p>Message DID NOT Sent. Please Try Again.</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you expect the validation to occur between the time the submit button is clicked and the time the request is sent to the server, or after the request is sent to the server?

Comment: So when is it validating or is it not validating at all? Where is `Error Handling Form` used?

Comment: Mike - between the time the submit button is clicked and the time the request is sent to the server.

@chris85 Currently, it's not validating at all. It did before I created comment-handler.php and set the action of the form equal to that. Before the form action was equal to "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" , and the validation worked, refreshed the screen when there were errors, and showed which inputs had errors.

Comment: So `commentform.php` == `Error Handling Form`? If so that is the problem. PHP is server side so it only available when the page is loading. When you click the submit it goes to `comment-handler.php` so your validation rules are never run. You could have an ajax check that sends on the form submit to `commentform.php` before actually submitting. (You'll still want a server side check though to avoid a malicious user that bypasses ajax).

Comment: Ok so how do I fix it. Never used an ajax check before. Could you either explain that? or do it I combine commenform.php and comment-handler.php, and how do I organize it to make sure the form doesn't submit unless it passes all validation rules?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick... let me know if I'm missing anything? or you need help understanding it?

Preview:

[image]

//PHTML

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    $POST = filter_post($_POST);
    $MSG = check_empty($POST);
    if(!array_filter($MSG)){
        if(send_mail($POST)){
            $MSG[] = "Email Success";
        }
        else{
            $MSG[] = "Email Failed";
        }
    }
}
function filter_post($POST){
    $keys = array('name','phone','email','comments');
    $POST = array_intersect_key($POST, array_flip($keys));  
    $POST = array_map('strip_tags', $POST); 
    return($POST);
}
function check_empty($POST){
    foreach($POST as $key => $value){
        if(empty($value)){
            $MSG[] = "You need to fill out the $key section";
        }
    }
    return($MSG);
}
function send_mail($POST){
    extract($POST);
    $to = '7servicerepairs@gmail.com';
    $sbj = 'New Question For Se7en Service!';       
    $msg = "Name = $name \n Phone = $phone \n Email = $email \n Comments = $comments";
    $headers = "From: $email";
    return(mail($to, $sbj, $msg, $headers));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
        <textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="10" placeholder="Please enter your comments here..."></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>             
    <mark><?php echo $MSG[0]; ?></mark>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -wekbit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #1E67CB;
}
form{
    cursor: default !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ECF0F1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
}
form>input{
    width: 22.1em;
    height: 2.5em;
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    outline: none;
}
form>button{
    width: 22.35em;
    height: 2.5em;
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2ECC71;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
form>textarea{
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    outline: none;
    max-width: 22em;
}
mark{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Form looks great and now I'm just in the testing. I received 4 test emails from you, assume you sent while creating the form... I tried sending a few tester email and I'm not receiving them...

Comment: @blackRob4953 check you spam you may have a strict email filter.

Comment: Way ahead of you ha. Nothing there. Plus, I received your test emails in my inbox. I modified some stuff but nothing crazy. Created a php file for //phtml. And placed that php file in the action of the form. Also included an if statement of php file to direct to a sent message screen if true or unsent screen if false. Currently it's always directing to the unsent screen. So its failing the if statement

Comment: @blackRob4953 got it yeah definitely the if statement on the success/fail for the email... give a min ill update the code.

Comment: Okay I just updated it... note that PHP mail function only returns TRUE for the correct email formats for delivery, NOT that the email msg actually got delivered... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (scroll to the return value for this function)

Comment: ok. edited the code. not sure if I'm just looking too much into this now. Now i'm getting an undefined index: name error for this line of code => <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">..... doesn't make sense how it can be undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87710/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-blackrob4953).